# What do these two screens mean and how to remove them?

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

I am new to ubuntu On the right it shows two screens

[image: On the right it shows two screens]

I accidentally opened two screens on the same desktop. They are visible on the right. I can see this on pressing the activities button on the top left. I want to know to create and especially delete this.

Comment: It is called virtual desktops. If you have lots of Windows open you can drag some to the bottom one. When you do a third virtual desktop will be made automatically. There is always one extra just in case you need one.

Comment: Is possible to just keep one and delete another one??

Comment: @AdityaShrivastava it is possible to have only one.. that means it will not show you when you press activities button or Windowskey/Super key..

Answer (score 1):

The right side two boxes are the Workspace No.1 and Workspace No.2 from Top to Bottom..

Your firefox window is on Workspace No.1, for example If you have another window opened on Workpsace No.1, you can move any one window to Workspace No.2 via keyboard shortcut or simply dragging and dropping it to No.2.

When you move one window to No.2, Workspace No.3 will be created automatically.

If you don't wish to use Workspaces and willing to have only Workspace No.1

Install `gnome-tweaks` with the below command

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

go to Workspaces tab and select Static Workspaces and choose Number of Workspaces to 1

[image]

Same thing can be achieved with out installing `gnome-tweaks` by command line way..

[image]